# How can I force a trigger to connect to a remote database using a specific account?

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle19c, dblink

On database "LOCAL" schema "USERS", I have a table "Accounts" .

On database "REMOTE" schema "USERS", I have the same table "Accounts".

The LOCAL.USERS.Accounts table includes an after insert/update/delete trigger that is intended to apply any LOCAL.USERS.Accounts edits to the REMOTE.USERS.Accounts table; to keep the data synchronized.

LOCAL.USERS has a public database link to REMOTE (one that does not specify `IDENTIFY AS`).

When I directly UPDATE LOCAL.USERS.Account, my changes are reflected immediately on REMOTE.USERS.Accounts -- the trigger works as intended.

However, when I try to use a package in LOCAL schema ACTORS to UPDATE LOCAL.USERS.Account, I get an error:

> ORA-01017: INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD; LOGON DENIED
> ORA-02063: PRECEDING LINE FROM REMOTE

The REMOTE database does not have a ACTORS schema, which I assume is the root of the problem.

How can I determine, from REMOTE's perspective, which schema is trying to connect? How can I force the trigger to apply edits to REMOTE as the USERS schema and not the ACTORS schema?

Comment: You can't. The database link must be defined to use a single username for *all* connections, or (as in your case it appears to be) to use the credentials of the current user. You cannot switch back and forth or force it one way or the other.

Comment: A connect account with privs to update a table should never be used by a public database link with credentials. Either create private db links in each schema that should have this kind of access to your remote, or use a credential-less public link and ensure you keep your schemas and passwords in sync between the two databases so the link will work. Keep in mind credential-less db links cannot be used by scheduler jobs, only by authenticated user sessions. For this reason, private db links in both LOCAL and ACTORS is probably your best bet.

Comment: Also note that public database links of any kind are  considered poor security practice and are typically prohibited by most auditing/hardening standards.

Comment: Quick apology--I originally wrote "LOCAL.USERS has a public synonym to REMOTE", but I *meant* "LOCAL.USERS has a public database link to REMOTE". Thinking one thing, typed another.

Comment: Further, in the quite-right spirit of distrusting public database links, I created a private database link and it resolved the problem. Noting the answer here in case anyone else comes across a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a private database link in the LOCAL USERS schema, with a `IDENTIFY AS USERS` clause, forced the trigger to connect to the REMOTE database as USERS (which has an account) and not ACTORS (which does not have an account on the remote database).